# How do I delete inspections (not the profile) from Webstorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, inspection

I added a Webstorm plugin that generated some inspections. Now I want to delete those inspections. Uninstalling the plugin removes the inspections, but when I reinstall they come back.

Comment: You can disable the inspections in the Project Settings. Isn't that enough for you?

Comment: You cannot "delete" inspections just like that if they came as part of some plugin -- they can only be removed together with that plugin. But you can easily disable those unwanted inspections (as @maba have already suggested).

Comment: I figured it out with some trial and error. The inspections were getting stored in .Idea folder inside the project directory. I deleted that and inspections were gone. Thanks :)

Comment: @Amit: You should never do that.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, could you please elaborate why not. I would like to know the repercussions. I am deleting the folder as I am working on a plugin that when run creates/stores inspections in .idea/misc.xml, hence I delete this file now, instead of deleting the whole folder.

Comment: Well the problem is that if you every use an EAP version of Webstorm, it will likey crash, since that is a file it looks for.